# PySide6, QTreeWidget, showing full column text as tooltip if and only if the column text is truncated

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6

I created a simple table with QTreeWidget. When a column's text is too long for the column width, it gets truncated with ellipses. Can I show the full text when the user hovers the mouse over the column?

I have tried the following code, but I do not know how to get if the text is truncated or not. Also, the tooltip may not be reliably appearing.

[image]

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem

data = {
    "Dog": "The dog is a domesticated descendant of the wolf.",
    "Cat": "Meow!"}

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

tree = QTreeWidget()
tree.setMouseTracking(True)
tree.setColumnCount(2)
tree.setHeaderLabels(["Animal", "Description"])
tree.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
tree.setColumnWidth(1, 100)

items = []
for key, value in data.items():
    item = QTreeWidgetItem([key, value])
    items.append(item)

tree.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)

def show_tooltip(item, column):
    row = tree.indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
    print(f"mouse hover over {row}, {column}");
    if column == 1:
        isTruncated = True #Somehow get if the current column text is truncated.
        if isTruncated:
            tree.setToolTip("Show the full column text")
        else:
            tree.setToolTip("")

tree.itemEntered.connect(show_tooltip)

tree.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It hardly seems worth the bother of trying to determine if the text is currently elided or not - just use [QTreeWidgetItem.setToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidgetitem.html#setToolTip) for that column and have done with it. Otherwise, you'll have to hack something together yourself using [QFontMetrics.elidedText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText) - but that won't always exactly match what QTreeWidget does. The layout of a view item is carried out by the style in a highly complex way, and the elided text value isn't publicly accessible.

Comment: Setting the tooltip for the whole view is not a good idea, as it may appear where it shouldn't (for example, the scroll bars). A better solution is to do that within a [`helpEvent()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#helpEvent) override of a QStyledItemDelegate. Unfortunately, there is no absolute way to know whether the text will be elided or not, because it completely depends on internal QStyle functions; you can only make assumptions based on the provided `SE_ItemViewItemText`, but the style may add further margins.